# Cost of Edition versus License

Tags: licenses, editions

I'm struggling to find clear answers about cost of the different license types. The cost of the different editions are easy to find, but I haven't been able to find anything about the cost of the different license types.

It looks like Sales Cloud Enterprise is $150/user/mo. But is the cost of the license in addition to the cost of the edition? Or is this all rolled in to the $150? If it's the former, could you send a link to the costs, if it exists? If it's the latter, is there any benefit to using different license types or is this a cost-savings strategy that has gone extinct?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi there, welcome! While this is a question better asked of your AE, I'll try a quick answer. The $150/user/month includes everything, including access to the org. There is no extra "Setup" cost, but there are numerous Add-Ons (Einstein, Community Users, etc) that you could purchase as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edition determines the cost of each standard CRM license. You cannot mix the various types of licenses. For example, it is not possible to get 5 Professional Edition Licenses and 10 Enterprise Edition Licenses. Either you are in Professional Edition, or you are in Enterprise Edition, and you would have 15 licenses total, given the example above.

In this sense, licensing is pretty straightforward. Note that salesforce.com has an undisclosed pricing matrix, so buying a significant number of licenses may be less expensive than the advertised price. This matrix is updated from time to time, and the pricing cannot be disclosed by customers, so your best option is to contact Sales or your Account Executive, if you already have one.

The prices are not a factor of "cost-saving", but rather, what you intend to do with your CRM. It's hard to tell you which you need, but most organizations go with Enterprise Edition, because it is easily integrated with external systems, has a ton of automation features, and is generally the most functional version for its price point.

I have personally never dealt with licensing, as I'm primarily a developer, but even from a developer standpoint, Professional Edition is great only if you have a small- or medium-sized business that's fairly compact, while Enterprise Edition is where the bulk of the useful features lie. Be sure you take the time to ask the right questions; you can always upgrade later, but downgrading is nigh-impossible for a variety of technical reasons.

Comment: I was under the impression that you could have different users (all using Enterprise edition, for example) using different license types - platform/Force.com/Salesforce.com (it seems like Salesforce changed the ways they refer to license types though, which makes it difficult to find information online that isn't seemingly outdated). And the users would have more or less access depending on the license type they had. Is that not the case? And if it is still possible, is there any benefit to limiting access apart from security/ease of use?

Comment: @Mplax Platform/Force.com/Salesforce.com all mean the same thing (the name has changed over time, the functionality has not). There are other types, like Partner, Chatter, and Community licenses, but those have specific purposes that are generally not well-suited for internal employees. Partner licenses for your partners (e.g. to share leads and opportunities), Chatter users for general communication only, and Community licenses for portals generally designed for customers. They also used to offer limited-login licenses for "lite" users, no idea if those still exist.

Comment: Then maybe I should have asked the same question above about Platform Starter and Platform Plus licenses? I appreciate the patience as I don't understand this at all! And the many names make it impossible...
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities_lightning_platform_details.htm&type=5

Comment: @Mplax You'll really want to talk to an AE. They can ask you all the right questions to help you determine the license(s) you need. Alternatively, a quick talk with a consultant would be useful. SFSE is a lot of things, but it's not a great format for determining what *your* organization needs to be successful with Salesforce. You need more personalized care that you'll only really find by talking to someone who knows the features and can have a dialogue about your org's needs.

Comment: I removed the line from my question that referenced that I am trying to deploy Salesforce for my company as it seems like you and Sebastian both picked up that I was looking for answers specific to my company. I really just want to know why there are different license types on top of the different editions, but I will try to look elsewhere for that answer. I will leave it to the admins as I don't want to delete the thorough answer you spent time on, but I would delete this thread to avoid future confusion for others.

Comment: @Mplax No worries, mods usually clean up threads that get too big. Anyways, the different types of licenses offer different features, like Chatter, CRM, Support, and so on. It would probably be useful to take a look at the various core features of Salesforce and determine which ones you need. Also, from a practical perspective, you can always upgrade later, so it might make sense to just start at a lower tier and work your way up as you grow with Salesforce.